# Sharepoint Eventlistener problem

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I've created a spfx webpart on a list page in SharePoint 2016. After selecting items in the list I click a button which calls `SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems().`

However, there is an eventlistener on the button added by SharePoint that deselects the items before I can get the ids. The `click event` looks like this:

```
body.ms-backgroundimage:http://av-dv/ScriptResource.axd?d=QlGFLwb4ffQZsPobR6ED1tzpe6s7gysC_vbFHz1hjBgqzuyVyzmWD9Lpsb2WPQkhZho-SjgwxKb4r9nHKqBm-N_dexDaGPS5gbkxoldei_v39JfFr9p2dCM9xo7KxdLH8BqYmwAqbEOf_MaidrarHCAVWU_vXSjblmxRNi3n4CBz80ji73a-Uao6iJGj9Qtg0&t=3d6efc1f.
```

It is visible using the devtools. How can I remove this event or better, how can I avoid the event bubble . I've tried e.preventDefault, e.stopPropagation() and return false. Removing the eventlistener manually using the devtool is the only way I can make it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: convert button to input submit and wrap it in a form and add an onSubmit handler.

```
  <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
      <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
 </form>

 handleSubmit = (e) => {
     alert(SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems().length);
     e.preventDefault();

  }
```